# Elastic search perform a result as LIKE SQL query

Tags: elasticsearch

In SQL query, i can query a LIKE query sample like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%a%'
```

How can i perform this in ElasticSearch. What all the steps i need to do also include insert data to elasticsearch from mysql using logstash?

Comment: First you need to prepare mapping (schema) for your data.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/partial-matching.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html